# jQuery load not always firing with <picture> element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, picturefill

I'm using the  element for responsive images with the picturefill polyfill for unsupported browsers. Everything works fine even in the unsupported browsers. But in chrome, where it is supported, my jquery load event isnt consistently firing. Heres my code:

```
$("#banner .banner-slide a img").load(mainSlider.init)
```

And my picture element:

```
<picture>
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcset="http://placehold.it/1920x300" media="(min-width: 1440px)" />
    <source srcset="http://placehold.it/1440x300" media="(min-width: 1024px)" />
    <source srcset="http://placehold.it/1024x250" media="(min-width: 640px)" />
    <source srcset="http://placehold.it/640x150" media="(min-width: 481px)" />
    <source srcset="http://placehold.it/480x150" media="(max-width: 480px)" />
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img srcset="http://placehold.it/1440x300" alt="" />
</picture>
```

Any idea as to what i can do to get it to work properly in chrome?

**Fixed**

Not too sure what the deal was but adding the below the load listener fixed it. Even with a setTimeout of 0 worked but to be save i gave it 10ms. Ive experienced a few scenarios before where a small timeout solves the problem with chrome.

```
//Fix chrome bug
setTimeout(function () {
    $(window).resize();
}, 10)
```

Comment: What is the code in `mainSlider.init`? What makes you believe it is not being executed?

Comment: It builds a slider using Slick slider. The height of the slider is dependent on the height of the image and sometimes the slider doesnt get a height. If i put a console.log inside mainSlider.init it only fires about 50% of the time

Comment: Does the fix still work if the cache is cleared? If not, try wrapping the `init` function in a `$(window).on('load' ...`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that sometimes the `load` event is fired before the listener is set up. Then you miss the event and nothing happens. This can happen in any browser.

To solve this you could use a capturing event listener, although that is not supported in old versions of IE.

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if (e.target === $("#banner .banner-slide a img")[0]) {
        mainSlider.init();
    }
}, true);
```

If you need to support old IE then you can use `onload="mainSlider.init();"` on the `img` or maybe `$(document).ready(mainSlider.init)`.

Note that you can get multiple `load` events on an `img` when using `srcset` or `picture` (when the image changes).